# Pythonic integer multiplication and addition

Tags: python, python-3.x, int, multiplication

I am finding problems in when I should use *= or be explicit in using my code. I'm trying to do simple integer multiplication and addition in Python. So to take a number, multiply it by 3 and add 1. Is there a specific situation where I should use:

```
number *= 3
number += 1
```

Or

```
number = (number * 3) + 1
```

Is there a difference between the two, or is this a matter of personal preference?

Comment: What looks clearer to you?

Comment: There is no difference other than how it looks, assuming `number` is an integer or a float.

Answer (score 4):

For simple values like integers, it won't usually make any difference and is a matter of style. For other objects it *may* make a difference, since `+` will invoke the `__add__` method and `+=` will invoke the `__iadd__` method if present, which updates the object itself. Simple example that comes to mind (here demonstrating `__ior__`):

```
foo = set('foo')
bar = foo

bar = bar | set('bar')
# vs
bar |= set('bar')
```

In this case the difference between `|` and `|=` is that the latter also modifies `foo`, while `|` does not.